# macOS Mojave pfctl disabled

Tags: networking, macos, macos-mojave

I have my pfctl enabled on my Mac and after I restart my laptop it's disabled. I noticed that sometimes when the laptop boots into Desktop the pfctl is enabled and then it gets disabled.

How can I find out what app/service/... is disabling the pfctl? Is there a log file for this (and where is it located)?

Is there a better alternative to pfctl so I can block some ports?

I only have couple of apps that start immediately: docker, istats, open vpn, express vpn, tunnelbrick, alfred4, Kitematic, Logitech mouse app

Answer (score 0):

You can check Lulu firewall `https://objective-see.com/products/lulu.html`.

> Network Monitoring
>   B
>   y design, LuLu only monitors for outgoing network connections. Apple's
>   built in firewall does a great job blocking unauthorized incoming
>   connections.
>
> Rules Currently, LuLu only supports rules at the 'process level',
>   meaning a process (or application) is either allowed to connect to the
>   network or not. As is the case with other firewalls, this also means
>   that if a legitimate (allowed) process is abused by malicious code to
>   perform network actions, this will be allowed.
>
> Single User For now, LuLu can only be installed for a single user.
>   Future versions will likely allow it to be installed by multiple users
>   on the same system.
>
> Self-Defense Legitimate attackers/security professionals know that any
>   security tool can be trivially bypassed if specifically targeted -
>   even if the tool employs advanced self-defense mechanisms. Such
>   self-defense mechanisms are often complex to implement and in the end,
>   almost always futile. As such, by design LuLu (currently) implements
>   few self-defense mechanisms. For example, an attacker could enumerate
>   all running processes to find the LuLu component responsible for
>   displaying alerts and terminate it (via a sigkill).